# R Package binaries for windows not available on R < 3.5, only being compiled 1x or 2x a year?

Tags: r

First, I know that on windows you can compile packages from source using Rtools. We are trying to avoid having to compile the packages locally.

Are the Windows binaries not being compiled for older versions of R? See screen shot below. Or are they only being compiled 1x a year or 2x a year? Updating to a newer version of R is not possible right now.

I am not familiar with the binary/windows/R packages process to know why this is happening. I know that volunteer(s) maintain this windows binary compilation and it happens automatically.

[image: Screen show from windows packages on CRAN]

Comment: (the last version of) R 3.4 came out 2 years ago. It's not realistic to expect CRAN to build packages indefinitely for an ever-increasing number of legacy versions (many of which contain serious bugs)

Comment: @alanocallaghan I completely agree. If they are no longer supporting older versions, then our organization needs to take the lengthy but necessary steps to update to a newer version. I'm trying to see if older versions are no longer being supported on a regular basis, then I have justification for getting our organization to update.

Comment: Fair. I don't know exactly how soon they stop support but as you can see from v 3.0/2.16, they do eventually become abandoned completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok looks like I eventually found the answer to my own question. Apparently we should always read the README section!
The binaries for R < 3.4 are no longer being supported.

https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/ReadMe

[image]

Comment: Seems like only devel, release and oldrelease are supported. Meaning 3.5 only has a few months left